# Prevent other server controls as children of a custom ASP.NET control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, custom-server-controls

Is there a way, other than creating a custom `ControlBuilder` class, to prevent server controls from being added as children in a custom ASP.NET control?

For example, let's say I am building my own `Panel` control:

```
<my:SpecialPanel ID="SpecialPanel1" runat="server">
    <!-- Allow valid HTML -->
    <input id="tbEmailAddress" type="text" />
</my:SpecialPanel>
```

I want to prevent users from adding server-side controls inside the `SpecialPanel`:

```
<my:SpecialPanel ID="SpecialPanel1" runat="server">
    <!-- WRONG - Throw an Exception -->
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbEmailAddress" runat="server" />
</my:SpecialPanel>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the [Control.AddParsedSubObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.addparsedsubobject.aspx) method:

```
public class SpecialPanel : Control
{
   protected override void AddParsedSubObject(Object obj) 
   {
      if (obj is Control) 
      {
         throw new InvalidOperationException(
             "The 'SpecialPanel' control cannot contain server controls");
      }
   }
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [IParserAccessor Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.iparseraccessor.aspx)

Comment: Excellent answer. Much simpler than building a custom control builder!